# Lie Derivative of a section on a vector bundle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-bundles, lie-derivative

I'm still trying to figure out how to do the Lie derivative of a Jacobian. (c.f. [earlier unanswered post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102484/lie-derivative-of-the-jacobian)).

If I know how how to do Lie derivatives on section of vector bundles, that would be sufficient. In my case the vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow X$ is given by the dual of the pullback bundle $E=(\phi^*TY)^*$, where $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a smooth map between smooth manifolds. **So let $\alpha$ be a section of that bundle. How do I define $\mathcal L_v\alpha$ ?** And it would be helpful also to know it in local coordinates.

*The reason why this would help me to define the Lie derivative of the Jacobian is that the Jacobian is a linear map from $TX\otimes (\pi^*TY)^*$ to $\mathbb R$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
(w,\alpha)_x\mapsto \langle D\phi\, w,\alpha\rangle_x\;
\end{equation}
where locally $w=\sum_iw^i(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\alpha=\sum_b\alpha^b(x)\,dy^b$ ($x^i$ a coords on $X$ and $y^b$ are coords on $Y$) and the pairing is $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_x: T_{\phi(x)}Y \times T^*_{\phi(x)}Y\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Then I could define $\big(\mathcal L_vD\phi\big) (w,\alpha)=\mathcal L_v \big(D\phi(w,\alpha)\big)-D\phi(\mathcal L_v w,\alpha)-D\phi(w,\mathcal L_v\alpha)$, knowing $\mathcal L_v\alpha$.*

Comment: The premise for defining the Lie derivative of tensor fields on $X$ is that you can use the flow of the vector field on $X$ to push forward and pull back in an obvious way. This is not going to make sense for a general vector bundle. I am pretty sure you need a connection on the bundle to attempt this.

Comment: Lie derivatives can be defined for sections of so called natural bundles. Firstly, in the case of tensor fields, it is enough to know the action of the Lie derivative on functions, vector fields and 1-forms, because then the general case is obtained via the Leibniz rule. Secondly, for more general geometric objects there is a notion of generalized Lie derivatives, which is better to learn about from the original source: I.Kolar, P.Michor, J. Slovak, Natural Operations in Differential Geometry, Chapter IX, pp. 376ff. Available [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Yuri for the very useful source. I will try to translate it for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material mentioned by Yuri in the comment can also be found in "Topics in differential geometry", available here
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf
by the same author, section 8.15. It may be a bit simpler than "Natural operations in differential geometry".

I was looking at the material right now. From what I have understood you need to be able to lift the flow of the vector field on the base  manifold to the total space of the vector bundle in such a way that

- the flow maps fibres to fibres
- the action on a given fibre is linear
- the lift of a smooth flow is smooth in the appropriate sense.

Given all this the Lie derivative can be defined in the usual why as the $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}t \,|_{t=0}\, \phi^*_t$ where $\phi$ is the lifted flow.

Of course for this to be useful you need to have some preferred/unique way of lifting the flow on the base to the total space.